# Security Record Rule OpenErp

Tags: security, odoo, rule

why it's possible in OpenErp

```
[(user.supplier,'=', True)]
```

and this not works

```
[(user.supplier,'=', False)]
```

Comment: did u try  with [(user.supplier,'!=', True)] ?

Answer (score 0):

Its actually wrong. 3 attributes used in domain are field_name, operator and value. field_name will be a field defined inside the model.

For which model you are actually creating this domain? If that model have a field called 'user' which is a many2one field having 'supplier' as a boolean field, then you can create a domain `[('user.supplier','=',True)]`

Answer (score 0):

your domain for True should be like this [('user.supplier','=',True)] and domain for False should be like this [('user.supplier','!=',True)]

This works for xml:

'boolean_field': fields.boolean("Test Boolean"),
'number_field': fields.integer("Test Number", size=10),

Comment: Please use back ticks and indention to format code. There should be a box on the edit screen that has hints on how to do this.